# Parsing bytestring into Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, django, string, dictionary

I have a bytestring like this:
`b'{\r\n    "hello": "world"\r\n}'`, retrieved from a request in JSON format. I would like to parse it into a Python dictionary so it looks like this: `{"hello": "world"}`. I have tried with `ast.literal_eval()` but that throws an error. How would you go about doing it?

Comment: You're missing the intermediary step of transforming your bytestring into a normal string by using `bytestring.decode('utf8')`. Also, don't forget to add minimum reproducible code to your questions as well as the stacktrace/full error that you are receiving and how you cause it!

Comment: `json.loads(b'{\r\n    "hello": "world"\r\n}')`